# Function which doesn't change the value

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm coding a 2D engine, and here is my problem :
Each tile have a 'texture' numero(0: grid, 1: grass, etc. ...)
When i try to change the numero like this :

```
maps[currentMapID].getLayerArray()[l].getTileArray()[t].setTexture(currentSelectedTexture);
```

*(l, t, etc. ... are from 'for' loop.)*

Nothing change, the numero is still 0.

Here is the code of `.setTexture(..)`:

```
void tile::setTexture(int t)
{
    numTexture = t;
}
```

This code is totally working when I create a test tile.

The structure of my code(classes) is :

```
Map > layer > tile. => all of them in a class wich handle graphics.
```

I suspect the problem coming from this (and same for `map class`, each of them have a `std::vector<layer>` and similiar function -> ) :

```
std::vector<tile> layer::getTileArray()
{
    return tiles;
}
```

Does it return me the `std::vector<layer>` from my class or a copy ? If it's a copy, it could explain that the tile's texture number remain the same.

if it's a copy, how can I change the `tile.numTexture` from another class ?? Pointers ? References ?(I don't really understand this one)

*I have also checked `currentSelectedTexture` and there is no problem there.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function

```
std::vector<tile> layer::getTileArray()
{
    return tiles;
}
```

returns a copy and you end up modifying the contents of the copy.

Change it to return a reference.

```
std::vector<tile>& layer::getTileArray()
{
    return tiles;
}
```

If the function `getLayerArray()` has similar signature, you will need to change that too.

Comment: I can't accept the answer right now(stackoverflow want me wait 10mn before accepting an answer), but just.. Thanks you so much, i was struggling with this problem for days and nights !